# Looking for text-to-phoneme or pronunciation data for English words

Tags: data-request, nlp

I am looking for data of text and their corresponding phonemes for the purpose of training a classification tree and a neural network.

Example: cat = k-a-t or something similar

I am looking for at least a few hundred words. If you have anything that will point me in the right direction, please do tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**#1** - For phonological equivalents of English words check out the [Irvine Phonotactic Online Dictionary](http://www.iphod.com/) (IPhOD) which is a collection of English words and non-words primarily intended for work in psycholinguistics and speech perception. You can d[ownload the entire database](http://www.iphod.com/download/) and see phonological entries like the following:
[image]
A corresponding table shows correspondence with the [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet):
[image]

**#2** - Another possibility is the [MRC Psycholnguistics database](http://websites.psychology.uwa.edu.au/school/MRCDatabase/uwa_mrc.htm), a searchable repository of words with accompanying properties of interest to psycholinguists: frequency, syntactic category, age of acquisition, pronunciation variability, etc.

[image]

Results are returned in text format with the accompanying features:

[image]

**#3** - Another possibility is the [USENET Orthographic Frequencies for 111,627 English Words](http://www.psych.ualberta.ca/~westburylab/downloads/wlfreq.download.html) - this data set is comprised of nearly 8 billion English-language tokens extracted from USENET 2005-2006. It includes the usual psycholinuistic suspects including a phonological translation.

[image]

**#4** - The [Carnegie Mellon University Pronouncing Dictionary](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict?in=for), which is open-source and machine-readable, contains over 134,000 words and their pronunciation is North American English. Their phoneme set has 39 phonemes, not counting variation due to lexical stress.

[image]